# Light reflection and refraction in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I have noticed when trying to make a mirror in Blender that it does not reflect light onto other objects properly.

Also, it seems that setting the IOR (Index of Refraction) for transparent objects does not effect light either.

How do I get reflection or refraction effects in Blender?

[image: Trying to reflect and refract in blender]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a ray-tracing render engine. Blender's internal render system has a ray-tracer, but it doesn't have the ability to reflect or refract light beams. You could possibly use [Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.61/Cycles) for this.

Comment: small clarification - blender-internal has a ray-tracer, it just doesn't support this feature.

Comment: @ideasman42 What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Dan the Man Blender Internal has raytracing capabilities, it just doesn't do caustics nor the features wanted in OP

Comment: Hmm, according to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17/does-cycles-work-with-wave-optics) it does not look like refraction is supported (yet).

Comment: Refraction is supported in both Cycles and Blender Internal, diffraction isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Refraction is now possible in the Blender Internal engine. Go to your material settings and enable transparency. Change the transparency type to raytrace. Turn the alpha to a low value (like 0) and you should see a refraction effect. You can change the IOR and fresnel too. A good IOR setting for glass would be 1.45.

[image: A screenshot showing the Blender Internal refraction capability]