# How to create iridescent glossy tile material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

I’ve got a [tile material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFGp.jpg) that I would love to recreate in Blender,

[image]

but my efforts have not been fruitful so far. As you can see in the picture, the tiles look like they're a solid color, except when light reflects off them at an angle. It's kind of like iridescence, although I'm not sure if it's actually iridescence.

Anyway, I've tried a few setups to recreate this. I tried applying a tile image texture and a kind of iridescent looking texture as a glossy texture in a mix shader, I tried this setup

[image]

from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles) which gave this result:

[image]
(click on the image to enlarge)

I also tried this setup, that I thought of myself,:

[image]
(Click on the image to enlarge)

which gave me this result:

[image]
(Click on the image to enlarge)

So, basically, I don't really know how to do this. Anyone have any advice or tips they could share? Thanks!

(https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4f8tb6/how_would_you_create_this_material_in_blender/) to see my results.

So, basically, I don't really know how to do this. If anyone has any idea, I would really appreciate the help, especially if you could explain it in a way that a blender beginner would understand. Thanks!

edit: basically I think the effect wouldn’t even have to be true iridescence. If somehow you could show an iridescent looking texture where light is reflected, that would solve this particular case. For instance, [this could be the regular tile texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UCfP.jpg) and [this could be the iridescent texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEnEm.jpg).

Comment: [see if this helps you](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles)

Comment: @RickRiggs: That's exactly what Flobin already posted in his Reddit post and cegaton inlined nicely into the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve something heading toward what you were describing anyway. I'm sure that there can be a lot of polish applied to this answer, especially on the cycle material nodes, but I believe that this will suffice to show the initial intent.

Here's the cycles material:

[image: CyclesMaterial_001]

Here's the demo of the setup:

[image: Demo_001]

The geometry is two parts:

1. The first part is the tile itself, set to a basic glass material.
2. Inside the tile is a highly subdivided plane with two copies of a displacement modifier, to break up the normal directions within the tile.

The cycles material does the rest of the heavy lifting.

Here's the blend for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the [second iridescence node setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles) suggested in the blender stack exchange link you linked to in your answer. With it, I created this:

[image]

I believe it to be the best way of doing things. If you choose to use this node setup, make sure the tiles are not perfectly flat and that you have smooth shading on. If you do not adhere to these two essential measures, there's a good chance the iridescence will fail.