# Blender Tempered Glass Effect

Tags: glass

Im wondering how i can make tempered glass in Blender 2.8. I'm looking for that "Rainbow Effect" in the glass that you may see on a camera lens for example. I wouldnt mind to share pics of what i have but i just have a principled shader for now and have no idea at all where to even start with node setup.

Comment: You should share both pictures of what you have, and reference pictures of the desired effect

Comment: Are you looking at diffraction effect in glass? Tempering just makes the glass stronger, it can have many looks.

Comment: Are you referring to birfringence?https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142274/heated-glass-material

Comment: @cegaton Yes. Thats correct. A similar result to that is what im looking for.

Comment: Related: [how to create iridescent glossy tile material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material/51449#51449) and [Physical iridescence in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles) and  [iridescence in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles)