How to create this solid glass refraction effect
I've been interested in solid glass refractions for a long time but I've never really figured it out.
Would love to hear from any experts who could outline a solid workflow for creating non-mechanical feeling refractions within solid "glass" objects such as this:


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material

This phenomenon is called birefringence. It involves polarized light as described in this video, and cannot be directly simulated in Blender with the built-in render engines. You would have to fake it with colored textures, possibly using reflection coordinates from the Texture Coordinates node. If you instead were looking for dispersion (making rainbows with prisms for example), see this question.

Hey, thanks for your answer. If nothing else, I already learned a thing!  Never heard the term birefringence before ;)

You’re welcome. I had to look it up because I remembered who made the video, but I didn’t remember the term lol.
