# gradient reflection-blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

my question is, what kind of a node setup do I need to achieve a similar effect ? 
(My starting point is principled BSDF with base colour , height map ,roughness map ,metalic map and normal map generated in Substance painter).

All help is greatly appreciated.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles

Comment: Watch [this part](https://youtu.be/JH3b1hj9EfU?t=1268) of the talk from the blender conference.

Comment: The only physically correct solution is custom OSL shaders that do this. Else you can only fake effects like thin-film coating, iridescence, diffraction, etc. Ideally you need spectral renderer which Cycles is not.