# How to create the cap from Back to the future (lenticular)

Tags: color

I want to create the **cap** from **Back to the future**
and i believe the color called "**lenticular**".

the color change per view like this i think.
[image]

this is the cap.
[image]

I hope someone can help me because i have no idea where to begin. ^^

Comment: Lenticular is a different phenomenon I think. What you want looks more like [iridescence](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=iridescence&tab=votes) I believe

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles I suspect is what you're looking for.
The lenticular idea is correct it changes based on viewing angle relative to surface angle.