# iridescent snake skin shader

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

I'm working on this snake and want it's skin to look like these reference images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is what I got so far but I don't think this is the optimal way. 
Any suggestions?

[image]

With [iridescent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1605/78972) shader from other question. But stil doesn't look like reference at all

[image]

Comment: I think the correct term is iridescent, not holographic, this will help if you want to find resources on this subject

Comment: Perhaps related: [Iridescence In Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1605/78972)

Comment: Hmm yes okay its iridescent. But how do I combine it with a shader/textures.

Comment: Hey :). The linked anwers output rgb color - plug it into Base color of the Principled BSDF

Comment: I tried as you can see in the added post but it still doesnt look like the references at all. I think it has to do something with the reflection from the looks of the reference

Comment: Looks good. You just have to match the colors...

Comment: But how to make it interactive with light? And color details on the scales? I don't think it looks good at all. Any more tips or suggestions?