# How to make this type of iridescent glass?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials

I have seen this iridescent soap bubble glass and wanted to recreate it. Does anyone know how to recreate it with shaders?

[image]

I have made like You said, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: it looks like a metal spiral in a glass marble with a bit of iridescence?

Comment: Maybe, I will try.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add a little tiny bit more details about what you have tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I think there's a bunch of postprocessing going on in that image. I also don't think the interesting color effect is iridescence but rather an artifact of light placement. Also, a good deal of the effect is due to the objects, like the mask in the lower left, being reflected by or transmitted through the sphere. I also don't think the inside spiral is metal.  I suspect it's blown glass, possibly of a different density.   Something like [this](https://www.palettecontemporary.com/marbles/clear-air-trap)

Comment: Here's a quick render of this "Clear Air Trap". It's what *moonboots* and *Marty Fouts* said (glass marble, glass spiral, iridescence shader, plus some glare from the compositor) => https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMuJp.jpg

Comment: Thanks. I will try to recreate, but are there any shader (I have searched it all around the internet) -> nothing? Would be very kind, if you attach blender file. Thanks.

Comment: The shader for the iridescence effect you can find here on BSE (linked in my answer below). But it's only one part, the other parts are the light in the scene, the point of view, the modifiers, the post effects in the compositor. -- I like your version. Looks abstract, kinda painted :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try to get something close to the reference image. But it's a guessing game since we don't know how it was created and little changes can completely change the appearance.

Let's use what *moonboots* and *Marty Fouts* wrote in the comments and go with **a glass marble, a glass spiral, an iridescence shader, plus some glare from the compositor**. The render engine is *Cycles*.

**The Marble**

Add an *Icoshpere* to the scene and give it a *Subsurface Division* modifier to make it more round. Set shading mode to *Shaded Smooth*. Add a *Solidify* modifier.

Activate add-on *Add Curve: Extra Objects* that comes with Blender. Then add an *Archimedean Spiral*. In the options panel that pops up, set *Spiral Type* to `Spheric` and *Turns* to `4`. In the curve properties, use the *Bevel* options to give it thickness. You also can use another curve object (Circle), edit it a little, and use this as a Bevel Object. It will distort the light that passes the spiral.

If you like to have things procedural you can "model" this with *Geometry Nodes*.

**Camera and Light**

Place the camera in front of the marble and a *Spot* light behind it. For the *Spot* light you can use an [IES profile](https://ieslibrary.com/en/browse) if you like.

To control the reflections you can add a *plane* over the marble or at one side.

[image: scene setup]

In the *World Properties* set up an *[HDRI](https://polyhaven.com/hdris)*. It has a huge impact on the appearance of the rendered image. Try different (night) HDRIs. You can turn down the *Strength* of the emission in the *Shader Editor* for the *World* properties.

**Iridescence Glass Shader**

Search here on BSE for *Iridescence* and you will find this question [Iridescence In Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2358/107598)?

We will use the node group from the top answer. Just add a *Hue Saturation Value* node to control the color spectrum better. (The *Hue* shifts the color palette of the *Color Ramp* node.)

[image: Iridescence node group]

To control the iridescence (more on the outside of the sphere, less in the center) we add a *Layer Weight* node and a *Color Ramp* node.

The *Principled BSDF* with *Transmission* set to `1` and very low *Roughness* is our glass shader.

[image: glass shader]

**Compositor**

Here you can add one or two *Glare* nodes, and a *Defocus* node if you want.

**Marble Examples**

[image: render examples]

1. uses Sahara Night HDRI
2. same as 1 but lowered the thickness of the *Solidify* modifier of the marble
3. like 1 but Blue Lagoone HDRI, tinted with a very light blue for (*Color 1* of the iridescence node group)
4. similar as 3, but bright plane on top and changed the color ramp values for the iridescence shader
5. this is *Marble 2*, no *Solifify* modifier on the marble but one on the spiral. Tinted spiral
6. same as 1 but increased the thickness of the *Solidify* modifier & black plane on top

**Blend File**

Materials and node setups for the objects and the world backgrounds are included, but no HDRIs. You can get them from [polyhaven.com](https://polyhaven.com/hdris).

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Wonderful answer, deserves much more upvotes. Embarrassing for everyone here :)