# How can I make plastic gradient material?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

[image][image]

I'm trying to make the material of this image. How can I make it?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-would-you-create-a-cd-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248694/someone-know-how-to-do-this-image-type-of-glass/248894#248894