# Physical iridescence in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, color, mathematics

Having recently seen the Siggraph paper **[A Practical Extension to Microfacet Theory for the Modeling of Varying Iridescence](https://belcour.github.io/blog/research/2017/05/01/brdf-thin-film.html)**, I of course said to myself "I have to have this in Blenderrrrr!" and started to experiment with a node setup to at least simulate it.

The paper, while not too long, is quite technical and mathy, and over my head. But I did glean some basic information from it (please point out any mistakes):

Iridescence is the result of a phase shift during refraction.

[image: Light wave refraction phase shift]

The colors of iridescence can be represented by drawing a spiral curve through a color space.

[image: A spiral curve through color space]

The color banding changes with the incident angle. So, of course the good ol' Fresnel effect is at play here. Seems logical to assume we need to have physically accurate Fresnel if we want to have physically accurate iridescence.

[image: Iridescence color changes with Fresnel]

It seems all this complex math can be represented in approximation by a color ramp! Heyyyy, I use color ramps all the time. Maybe this won't be so hard after all.

I don't know what $\mathcal{D}_\text{inc}$ is though... (no dinc jokes in the comments, please). If you know what it means, please comment or answer.

[image: A ColorRamp! This is starting to look familiar.]

Could this approximation be perhaps close enough for our practical rendering purposes?

Let's take our screen shot of the gradient and crop it:

[image: Cropped image of iridescent color gradient]

Instead of painstakingly setting hundreds of gradient stops for the color bands we can plug in the cropped image of the gradient with the vector data from a Layer Weight node like this:

[image: Cycles node setup for an image gradient]

Now we have fake iridescent color!

[image: Suzanne using the new and stylish iridescent gradient]

From here I've been experimenting with PBR node setups and trying to plug this gradient color data in in some meaningful way. I've made some neat looking materials, but as far as physical accuracy goes, I can't say I've made much progress. Since my understanding of the paper is incomplete, I'm asking the community: Can we create an iridescence shader like the one described in this paper, in Cycles?

Comment: For Dinc check here: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01518344/file/supp-mat-small.pdf Second paragraph. I'm totally dumb in maths (and physics with optics included) but Dinc (for me) looks like thin-film layer thickness. Don't take my word for it, I'm probably (mostly) wrong.

Comment: I've searched a little bit about it and statement from the paper intro: *"this theory requires spectral rendering engines"* is not good for us. From here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17/does-cycles-work-with-wave-optics *"As Cycles is a RGB-based raytracer, not a spectral raytracer, it's based on single paths for all colors(with the colors changing at every bounce/transmit). Therefore, dispersion cannot be simulated directly."* And now I'm sad.

Comment: But there is it from @brecht: *"Strictly speaking Cycles wouldn't need to be a spectral renderer to support dispersion, it can be fit in without that."*

Comment: I've been experimenting here after looking at your post, and it seems that I was able to come to a closer point of realism, if I added a noise Texture, and multiply Math node, and plugged that into displacement... then If you bump up the noise scale really high, you begin to cause a physical micro-facet to occur, because you are changing the way that the "bumps" reflect light, the higher the scale the more the micro.

Comment: @RickRiggs Awesome! If you don't mind posting a Blend Exchange link in a comment I'd love to check it out.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I was just playing here, but also tried to incorporate your efforts into the experiment.

As far as the goal I was shooting for:

I was referring to the chair material found in your provided link

[As requested, here is my experiments:](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3503/)

Comment: @RickRiggs Thanks for sharing your experimentation. :-)

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?433309-Micro-angle-dependent-Roughness-amp-Iridescence/page14

Comment: http://polycount.com/discussion/comment/2604578/#Comment_2604578

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1605/599

Answer (score 1):

"You DO have this in Blenderrrrr!" since POV-Ray does support Newton's thin-film coating under the iridescence keyword: [image]

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, and good to know. However, please note that I did specify in my question title that I am looking to do this within the Cycles render engine.

Comment: This video might be helpful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjMjWtntm9k