# How to get transparent iridescence using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, light, transparency

I've succeeded getting iridescent with this Cycles node setup:

[Physical iridescence in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles)

This did the job, however I need a transparent/clear iridescence like this

[image]

So I tried plugging the final output into a mix shader between Glass BDSF and transparent. However this still produces a black, barely iridescent material.

How can I get the results below from what I have? I don't want to use code but rather stay with nodes

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/gpu-compatible-thin-film-interference-v2-1-glass-within-glass-absorption/699459) on Blender Artists. I've jumped you to the Node-Based version: you can track back to the OSL if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't Mix but Add** your Shader to a Transparent BSDF. You may also want to multiply the *Emission* strength by some value less than 1: (in red my changes to [Mentalist's version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82705/16395)):

[image]

The result:

[image]